# Python "higher/lower" game not working as expected

Tags: python, csv

The game works like this: the user is given a google search term like : "limousine" and the monthly searches the term has, then it is presented with another term. The user has to guess if the latter term has a higher or lower number of searches in order to receive a point. When running the python script I have encountered confusing behavior. Even though the answer is right the game stops.

```
import pandas
from random import choice, randint

columnNames = ['search','number_of_searches']
search_registry = pandas.read_csv('data.csv', names = columnNames)

keywords = search_registry.search.tolist()
values = search_registry.number_of_searches.tolist()

points = 0
stop = 0

while stop != 1:

    randomIndex_1 = randint(1,len(keywords)-1)
    print ( keywords[randomIndex_1] + " has {} monthly global searches ".format(values[randomIndex_1]) )

    randomIndex_2 = choice([i for i in range(1,len(keywords)) if i != randomIndex_1])
    print ( "How many does {} have? Higher or Lower?".format(keywords[randomIndex_2]))

    ans = input()

    if ans == 'higher':
        if values[randomIndex_1] < values[randomIndex_2]:
            points+=1
        elif values[randomIndex_1] > values[randomIndex_2]:
            print("GAME OVER. You got {} points".format(points))
            stop=1

    if ans == 'lower':
        if values[randomIndex_1] > values[randomIndex_2]:
            points+=1
        elif values[randomIndex_1] < values[randomIndex_2]:
            print("GAME OVER. You got {} points".format(points))
            stop=1
```

This is the CSV data:

```
"search","number_of_searches"
"Rolex",2740000,
"April The Giraffe",1500000,
"Scarlet Johansson",3350000,
"Maldives",1220000,
"Fargo",823000,
"Profiteroles",201000,
"Road Runner",369000,
"Limousine",246000,
"Birthday Cake",2250000,
"The Secret",301000,
"Ralph Lauren",2240000,
"The Silence Of The Lambs",368000
```

Comment: Use  [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to debug.

Comment: Just guessing here - from a cursory glance over your code and data: think about what happens with your "headerline" indisde your csv. Think about what resulting datatypes your pandas columns get if they contain mixed "text" and "numbers" - think about what ramification this might have for the comparing operators of < >. Then debug it. Prepare for data that is equal as well in case you introduce those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved. The `values[]` list stores data of type `str` not `int`. Simply writing `int(values[])` when comparing will resolve the issue. Now the comparison is done between `int` types not between strings.